# cabal dependency resolution fail for 'lens'

Tags: haskell, cabal

I just did a cabal update and tried to install 'lens' from hackage. That gave me the following error -

```
$ cabal install -j lens
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring dlist-0.7.0.1...
... <snip>
Configuring mtl-2.0.1.0...
Building mtl-2.0.1.0...
Failed to install mtl-2.0.1.0
Last 10 lines of the build log ( /home/aj/.cabal/logs/mtl-2.0.1.0.log ):
Building mtl-2.0.1.0...
Preprocessing library mtl-2.0.1.0...
[ 1 of 21] Compiling Control.Monad.Writer.Class (
Control/Monad/Writer/Class.hs, dist/build/Control/Monad/Writer/Class.o )
[ 2 of 21] Compiling Control.Monad.State.Class ( Control/Monad/State/Class.hs,
dist/build/Control/Monad/State/Class.o )
[ 3 of 21] Compiling Control.Monad.Reader.Class (
Control/Monad/Reader/Class.hs, dist/build/Control/Monad/Reader/Class.o )
[ 4 of 21] Compiling Control.Monad.RWS.Class ( Control/Monad/RWS/Class.hs,
dist/build/Control/Monad/RWS/Class.o )
[ 5 of 21] Compiling Control.Monad.Identity ( Control/Monad/Identity.hs,
dist/build/Control/Monad/Identity.o )
[ 6 of 21] Compiling Control.Monad.Error.Class ( Control/Monad/Error/Class.hs,
dist/build/Control/Monad/Error/Class.o )
Control/Monad/Error/Class.hs:93:18: Not in scope: `catch'
... <snip>
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
aeson-0.7.0.3 depends on mtl-2.0.1.0 which failed to install.
exceptions-0.6 depends on mtl-2.0.1.0 which failed to install.
free-4.7.1 depends on mtl-2.0.1.0 which failed to install.
lens-4.1.2 depends on mtl-2.0.1.0 which failed to install.
mtl-2.0.1.0 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

So looks like mtl-2.0.1.0 is broken. However some more dependency tracking reveals that nothing in the lens package definition actually depends on that version of mtl. Infact, the next thing I tried was -

```
$ cabal install -j aeson
$ cabal install -j free
$ cabal install -j lens
```

And that succeeds without problems.

So why would cabal try to install `mtl-2.0.1.0` when installing `lens` directly? I've tried removing my .ghc and .cabal directories and repeating the steps, with the same results. The cabal version I'm using is 1.16 -

```
$ cabal -V
cabal-install version 1.16.0.2
using version 1.16.0 of the Cabal library
```

Comment: This is related to the recent update of `transformers`. If you could wait a few days until the packages depending on `transformers` are upgraded, you shouldn't run into any issues installing `lens`.

Comment: @DannyNavarro Well I did manage to get lens installed using the method above. The question is more of a - why, if `cabal install lens` fails, would `cabal install aeson && cabal install free && cabal install lens` work?

Comment: I guess it's working because, by installing first `free` and `aeson`, you are forcing `cabal` to use the installed versions instead picking them by itself. It seems to pick some package version that uses `mtl-2.0.1.0`. Maybe it's an upper bounds in `aeson` or `free` dependencies, but most likely it'll be some other package deeper in the dependency graph.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround that I am using is to first install transformers-compat with the transformers 3 flag

```
$ cabal install -ftransformer3 transformers-compat
```

and then install lens with the transformers 0.3.0.0 constraint

```
$ cabal install --constraint="transformers==0.3.0.0" lens
```

Answer (score 0):

I hit this error too. I think I've managed to fix it by manually unpacking `mtl-2.0.1.0`, explicitly adding `catch` to the import list of `Control.Exception` in `Control/Monad/Error/Class.hs` (L:55), then running `cabal install`.

After that I was able to run `cabal install lens`. I'd be interested to know if that works for you too!