# Cabal: Cryptonite failed to install

Tags: haskell, dependencies, cabal, yesod

I tried to install Yesod with Cabal. Yesod depends on Cryptonite to work, however it failed to install. Here is the error message:

```
the-inquiry@the-inquiry-pc:~/workspace$ cabal install cryptonite
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring cryptonite-0.11...
Building cryptonite-0.11...
Failed to install cryptonite-0.11
Build log ( /home/the-inquiry/.cabal/logs/cryptonite-0.11.log ):
Configuring cryptonite-0.11...
Building cryptonite-0.11...
Preprocessing library cryptonite-0.11...
[  1 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Internal.CompatPrim ( Crypto/Internal/CompatPrim.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Internal/CompatPrim.o )
[  2 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Random.Entropy.Source ( Crypto/Random/Entropy/Source.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Random/Entropy/Source.o )
[  3 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Random.Entropy.Unix ( Crypto/Random/Entropy/Unix.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Random/Entropy/Unix.o )
[  4 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Internal.Words ( Crypto/Internal/Words.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Internal/Words.o )
[  5 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Random.Entropy.Backend ( Crypto/Random/Entropy/Backend.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Random/Entropy/Backend.o )
[  6 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Random.Entropy.Unsafe ( Crypto/Random/Entropy/Unsafe.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Random/Entropy/Unsafe.o )
[  7 of 101] Compiling Crypto.PubKey.Internal ( Crypto/PubKey/Internal.hs, dist/build/Crypto/PubKey/Internal.o )
[  8 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Number.Compat ( Crypto/Number/Compat.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Number/Compat.o )
[  9 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Number.Basic ( Crypto/Number/Basic.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Number/Basic.o )
[ 10 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Number.ModArithmetic ( Crypto/Number/ModArithmetic.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Number/ModArithmetic.o )
[ 11 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Number.Serialize.Internal ( Crypto/Number/Serialize/Internal.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Number/Serialize/Internal.o )
[ 12 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Internal.DeepSeq ( Crypto/Internal/DeepSeq.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Internal/DeepSeq.o )
[ 13 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Data.Padding ( Crypto/Data/Padding.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Data/Padding.o )
[ 14 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Cipher.DES.Primitive ( Crypto/Cipher/DES/Primitive.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Cipher/DES/Primitive.o )
[ 15 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Internal.Compat ( Crypto/Internal/Compat.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Internal/Compat.o )
[ 16 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Internal.WordArray ( Crypto/Internal/WordArray.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Internal/WordArray.o )
[ 17 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Cipher.Blowfish.Box ( Crypto/Cipher/Blowfish/Box.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Cipher/Blowfish/Box.o )
[ 18 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Internal.ByteArray ( Crypto/Internal/ByteArray.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Internal/ByteArray.o )
[ 19 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Number.Serialize ( Crypto/Number/Serialize.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Number/Serialize.o )
[ 20 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Random.Entropy ( Crypto/Random/Entropy.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Random/Entropy.o )
[ 21 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Random.EntropyPool ( Crypto/Random/EntropyPool.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Random/EntropyPool.o )
[ 22 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Cipher.Types.Utils ( Crypto/Cipher/Types/Utils.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Cipher/Types/Utils.o )
[ 23 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Internal.Imports ( Crypto/Internal/Imports.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Internal/Imports.o )
[ 24 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Cipher.ChaCha ( Crypto/Cipher/ChaCha.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Cipher/ChaCha.o )
[ 25 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Cipher.RC4 ( Crypto/Cipher/RC4.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Cipher/RC4.o )
[ 26 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Cipher.Salsa ( Crypto/Cipher/Salsa.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Cipher/Salsa.o )
[ 27 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Random.Types ( Crypto/Random/Types.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Random/Types.o )
[ 28 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Error.Types ( Crypto/Error/Types.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Error/Types.o )
[ 29 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Number.F2m ( Crypto/Number/F2m.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Number/F2m.o )
[ 30 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Number.Generate ( Crypto/Number/Generate.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Number/Generate.o )
[ 31 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Hash.Types ( Crypto/Hash/Types.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Hash/Types.o )
[ 32 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Hash.IO   ( Crypto/Hash/IO.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Hash/IO.o )
[ 33 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Hash.Blake2s ( Crypto/Hash/Blake2s.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Hash/Blake2s.o )
[ 34 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Hash.Blake2sp ( Crypto/Hash/Blake2sp.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Hash/Blake2sp.o )
[ 35 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Hash.Blake2b ( Crypto/Hash/Blake2b.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Hash/Blake2b.o )
[ 36 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Hash.Blake2bp ( Crypto/Hash/Blake2bp.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Hash/Blake2bp.o )
[ 37 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Hash.MD2  ( Crypto/Hash/MD2.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Hash/MD2.o )
[ 38 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Hash.MD4  ( Crypto/Hash/MD4.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Hash/MD4.o )
[ 39 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Hash.MD5  ( Crypto/Hash/MD5.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Hash/MD5.o )
[ 40 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Hash.SHA1 ( Crypto/Hash/SHA1.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Hash/SHA1.o )
[ 41 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Hash.SHA224 ( Crypto/Hash/SHA224.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Hash/SHA224.o )
[ 42 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Hash.SHA256 ( Crypto/Hash/SHA256.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Hash/SHA256.o )
[ 43 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Hash.SHA384 ( Crypto/Hash/SHA384.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Hash/SHA384.o )
[ 44 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Hash.SHA512 ( Crypto/Hash/SHA512.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Hash/SHA512.o )
[ 45 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Hash.SHA512t ( Crypto/Hash/SHA512t.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Hash/SHA512t.o )
[ 46 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Hash.SHA3 ( Crypto/Hash/SHA3.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Hash/SHA3.o )
[ 47 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Hash.Keccak ( Crypto/Hash/Keccak.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Hash/Keccak.o )
[ 48 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Hash.RIPEMD160 ( Crypto/Hash/RIPEMD160.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Hash/RIPEMD160.o )
[ 49 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Hash.Tiger ( Crypto/Hash/Tiger.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Hash/Tiger.o )
[ 50 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Hash.Skein256 ( Crypto/Hash/Skein256.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Hash/Skein256.o )
[ 51 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Hash.Skein512 ( Crypto/Hash/Skein512.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Hash/Skein512.o )
[ 52 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Hash.Whirlpool ( Crypto/Hash/Whirlpool.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Hash/Whirlpool.o )
[ 53 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Hash.Algorithms ( Crypto/Hash/Algorithms.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Hash/Algorithms.o )
[ 54 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Hash      ( Crypto/Hash.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Hash.o )
[ 55 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Data.AFIS ( Crypto/Data/AFIS.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Data/AFIS.o )
[ 56 of 101] Compiling Crypto.MAC.HMAC  ( Crypto/MAC/HMAC.hs, dist/build/Crypto/MAC/HMAC.o )
[ 57 of 101] Compiling Crypto.KDF.PBKDF2 ( Crypto/KDF/PBKDF2.hs, dist/build/Crypto/KDF/PBKDF2.o )
[ 58 of 101] Compiling Crypto.KDF.Scrypt ( Crypto/KDF/Scrypt.hs, dist/build/Crypto/KDF/Scrypt.o )
[ 59 of 101] Compiling Crypto.KDF.HKDF  ( Crypto/KDF/HKDF.hs, dist/build/Crypto/KDF/HKDF.o )
[ 60 of 101] Compiling Crypto.PubKey.MaskGenFunction ( Crypto/PubKey/MaskGenFunction.hs, dist/build/Crypto/PubKey/MaskGenFunction.o )
[ 61 of 101] Compiling Crypto.PubKey.DSA ( Crypto/PubKey/DSA.hs, dist/build/Crypto/PubKey/DSA.o )
[ 62 of 101] Compiling Crypto.PubKey.ECC.Types ( Crypto/PubKey/ECC/Types.hs, dist/build/Crypto/PubKey/ECC/Types.o )
[ 63 of 101] Compiling Crypto.PubKey.RSA.Types ( Crypto/PubKey/RSA/Types.hs, dist/build/Crypto/PubKey/RSA/Types.o )
[ 64 of 101] Compiling Crypto.PubKey.RSA.Prim ( Crypto/PubKey/RSA/Prim.hs, dist/build/Crypto/PubKey/RSA/Prim.o )
[ 65 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Random.ChaChaDRG ( Crypto/Random/ChaChaDRG.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Random/ChaChaDRG.o )
[ 66 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Random.SystemDRG ( Crypto/Random/SystemDRG.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Random/SystemDRG.o )
[ 67 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Random    ( Crypto/Random.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Random.o )
[ 68 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Random.Probabilistic ( Crypto/Random/Probabilistic.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Random/Probabilistic.o )
[ 69 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Number.Prime ( Crypto/Number/Prime.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Number/Prime.o )
[ 70 of 101] Compiling Crypto.PubKey.DH ( Crypto/PubKey/DH.hs, dist/build/Crypto/PubKey/DH.o )
[ 71 of 101] Compiling Crypto.PubKey.RSA ( Crypto/PubKey/RSA.hs, dist/build/Crypto/PubKey/RSA.o )
[ 72 of 101] Compiling Crypto.PubKey.RSA.PKCS15 ( Crypto/PubKey/RSA/PKCS15.hs, dist/build/Crypto/PubKey/RSA/PKCS15.o )
[ 73 of 101] Compiling Crypto.PubKey.RSA.PSS ( Crypto/PubKey/RSA/PSS.hs, dist/build/Crypto/PubKey/RSA/PSS.o )
[ 74 of 101] Compiling Crypto.PubKey.RSA.OAEP ( Crypto/PubKey/RSA/OAEP.hs, dist/build/Crypto/PubKey/RSA/OAEP.o )
[ 75 of 101] Compiling Crypto.PubKey.ECC.Prim ( Crypto/PubKey/ECC/Prim.hs, dist/build/Crypto/PubKey/ECC/Prim.o )
[ 76 of 101] Compiling Crypto.PubKey.ECC.ECDSA ( Crypto/PubKey/ECC/ECDSA.hs, dist/build/Crypto/PubKey/ECC/ECDSA.o )
[ 77 of 101] Compiling Crypto.PubKey.ECC.Generate ( Crypto/PubKey/ECC/Generate.hs, dist/build/Crypto/PubKey/ECC/Generate.o )
[ 78 of 101] Compiling Crypto.PubKey.ECC.DH ( Crypto/PubKey/ECC/DH.hs, dist/build/Crypto/PubKey/ECC/DH.o )
[ 79 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Cipher.Types.GF ( Crypto/Cipher/Types/GF.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Cipher/Types/GF.o )
[ 80 of 101] Compiling Crypto.PubKey.ElGamal ( Crypto/PubKey/ElGamal.hs, dist/build/Crypto/PubKey/ElGamal.o )
[ 81 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Error     ( Crypto/Error.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Error.o )
[ 82 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Cipher.Blowfish.Primitive ( Crypto/Cipher/Blowfish/Primitive.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Cipher/Blowfish/Primitive.o )
[ 83 of 101] Compiling Crypto.KDF.BCrypt ( Crypto/KDF/BCrypt.hs, dist/build/Crypto/KDF/BCrypt.o )
[ 84 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Cipher.Camellia.Primitive ( Crypto/Cipher/Camellia/Primitive.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Cipher/Camellia/Primitive.o )
[ 85 of 101] Compiling Crypto.MAC.Poly1305 ( Crypto/MAC/Poly1305.hs, dist/build/Crypto/MAC/Poly1305.o )
[ 86 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Cipher.ChaChaPoly1305 ( Crypto/Cipher/ChaChaPoly1305.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Cipher/ChaChaPoly1305.o )
[ 87 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Cipher.Types.Base ( Crypto/Cipher/Types/Base.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Cipher/Types/Base.o )
[ 88 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Cipher.Types.AEAD ( Crypto/Cipher/Types/AEAD.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Cipher/Types/AEAD.o )
[ 89 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Cipher.Types.Block ( Crypto/Cipher/Types/Block.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Cipher/Types/Block.o )
[ 90 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Cipher.Types.Stream ( Crypto/Cipher/Types/Stream.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Cipher/Types/Stream.o )
[ 91 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Cipher.Types ( Crypto/Cipher/Types.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Cipher/Types.o )
[ 92 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Cipher.AES.Primitive ( Crypto/Cipher/AES/Primitive.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Cipher/AES/Primitive.o )
[ 93 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Cipher.Blowfish ( Crypto/Cipher/Blowfish.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Cipher/Blowfish.o )
[ 94 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Cipher.Camellia ( Crypto/Cipher/Camellia.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Cipher/Camellia.o )
[ 95 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Cipher.DES ( Crypto/Cipher/DES.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Cipher/DES.o )
[ 96 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Cipher.TripleDES ( Crypto/Cipher/TripleDES.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Cipher/TripleDES.o )
[ 97 of 101] Compiling Crypto.PubKey.Curve25519 ( Crypto/PubKey/Curve25519.hs, dist/build/Crypto/PubKey/Curve25519.o )
[ 98 of 101] Compiling Crypto.PubKey.ECC.P256 ( Crypto/PubKey/ECC/P256.hs, dist/build/Crypto/PubKey/ECC/P256.o )
[ 99 of 101] Compiling Crypto.PubKey.Ed25519 ( Crypto/PubKey/Ed25519.hs, dist/build/Crypto/PubKey/Ed25519.o )
[100 of 101] Compiling Crypto.PubKey.Ed448 ( Crypto/PubKey/Ed448.hs, dist/build/Crypto/PubKey/Ed448.o )
[101 of 101] Compiling Crypto.Cipher.AES ( Crypto/Cipher/AES.hs, dist/build/Crypto/Cipher/AES.o )

cbits/ed448/x448.c:21:9:
     error: unknown type name ‘__uint128_t’
     typedef __uint128_t decaf_dword_t;
             ^

cbits/ed448/x448.c:22:9:
     error: unknown type name ‘__int128_t’
     typedef __int128_t decaf_sdword_t;
             ^
cbits/ed448/x448.c: In function ‘gf_mul’:

cbits/ed448/x448.c:83:48:
     warning: right shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
         accum[X448_LIMBS-1] += accum[X448_LIMBS-2] >> LBITS;
                                                    ^

cbits/ed448/x448.c:85:48:
     warning: right shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
         accum[X448_LIMBS/2] += accum[X448_LIMBS-1] >> LBITS;
                                                    ^

cbits/ed448/x448.c:87:45:
     warning: right shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
             accum[j] += accum[(j-1)%X448_LIMBS] >> LBITS;
                                                 ^

cbits/ed448/x448.c:50:8:
     note: in definition of macro ‘FOR_LIMB_U’
            op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; \
            ^

cbits/ed448/x448.c:87:45:
     warning: right shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
             accum[j] += accum[(j-1)%X448_LIMBS] >> LBITS;
                                                 ^

cbits/ed448/x448.c:50:16:
     note: in definition of macro ‘FOR_LIMB_U’
            op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; \
                    ^

cbits/ed448/x448.c:87:45:
     warning: right shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
             accum[j] += accum[(j-1)%X448_LIMBS] >> LBITS;
                                                 ^

cbits/ed448/x448.c:50:24:
     note: in definition of macro ‘FOR_LIMB_U’
            op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; \
                            ^

cbits/ed448/x448.c:87:45:
     warning: right shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
             accum[j] += accum[(j-1)%X448_LIMBS] >> LBITS;
                                                 ^

cbits/ed448/x448.c:50:32:
     note: in definition of macro ‘FOR_LIMB_U’
            op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; \
                                    ^

cbits/ed448/x448.c:87:45:
     warning: right shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
             accum[j] += accum[(j-1)%X448_LIMBS] >> LBITS;
                                                 ^

cbits/ed448/x448.c:50:40:
     note: in definition of macro ‘FOR_LIMB_U’
            op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; \
                                            ^

cbits/ed448/x448.c:87:45:
     warning: right shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
             accum[j] += accum[(j-1)%X448_LIMBS] >> LBITS;
                                                 ^

cbits/ed448/x448.c:50:48:
     note: in definition of macro ‘FOR_LIMB_U’
            op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; \
                                                    ^

cbits/ed448/x448.c:87:45:
     warning: right shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
             accum[j] += accum[(j-1)%X448_LIMBS] >> LBITS;
                                                 ^

cbits/ed448/x448.c:50:56:
     note: in definition of macro ‘FOR_LIMB_U’
            op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; \
                                                            ^

cbits/ed448/x448.c:87:45:
     warning: right shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
             accum[j] += accum[(j-1)%X448_LIMBS] >> LBITS;
                                                 ^

cbits/ed448/x448.c:50:64:
     note: in definition of macro ‘FOR_LIMB_U’
            op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; op;i++; \
                                                                    ^
cbits/ed448/x448.c: In function ‘gf_canon’:

cbits/ed448/x448.c:186:15:
     warning: right shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
             carry >>= LBITS;
                   ^

cbits/ed448/x448.c:64:76:
     note: in definition of macro ‘FOR_LIMB’
     #define FOR_LIMB(i,op) { unsigned int i=0; for (i=0; i<X448_LIMBS; i++)  { op; }}
                                                                                ^

cbits/ed448/x448.c:196:15:
     warning: right shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
             carry >>= LBITS;
                   ^

cbits/ed448/x448.c:64:76:
     note: in definition of macro ‘FOR_LIMB’
     #define FOR_LIMB(i,op) { unsigned int i=0; for (i=0; i<X448_LIMBS; i++)  { op; }}
                                                                                ^
cbits/ed448/x448.c: In function ‘gf_deser’:

cbits/ed448/x448.c:207:91:
     warning: right shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
             for (bits += 8; (bits>=LBITS || i==X448_BYTES-1) && k<X448_LIMBS; bits-=LBITS, buf>>=LBITS) {
                                                                                               ^

cbits/ed448/x448.c:213:59:
     warning: right shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
         FOR_LIMB(i, accum = (accum + s->limb[i] - P->limb[i]) >> WBITS );
                                                               ^

cbits/ed448/x448.c:64:76:
     note: in definition of macro ‘FOR_LIMB’
     #define FOR_LIMB(i,op) { unsigned int i=0; for (i=0; i<X448_LIMBS; i++)  { op; }}
                                                                                ^
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
cryptonite-0.11 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

I've already tried the following solution but it gave the same error message: 
[cabal dependency resolution fail for 'lens'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23510242/cabal-dependency-resolution-fail-for-lens)

My OS is Ubuntu 15.10

Thank you

Comment: Note that the recommended way of [installing Yesod](http://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart) is by using Stack.

Comment: Yes I've tried that too.

Comment: Does that work ? If it doesn't, then it's a bug. But the last time I tried, it worked for me perfectly.

Comment: Initially no, but I tried to it on a 64-bit system and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant part seems to be the next:

```
cbits/ed448/x448.c:21:9:
     error: unknown type name ‘__uint128_t’
     typedef __uint128_t decaf_dword_t;
             ^
```

AFAIK `__uint128_t` is a `gcc` [extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html#_005f_005fint128), so it is probably not available with your compiler. Try to contact [package maintainer](https://github.com/haskell-crypto/cryptonite/issues).

ADD: Are you using `i686` architecture? Looks like the issue is already [reported](https://github.com/haskell-crypto/cryptonite/issues/67).

Comment: I was using a i686 architecture. problem solved, thanks.